# Fetching many to many data from prisma findMany

Tags: reactjs, next.js, crud, prisma

Currently I am working with next.js crud prisma with many-to-many relation. I am able to create all the end point for my crud operation. Now I am working on connection it to the client side which would display student with the class that student is attending. I am able to map my students and display their name but I am struggling to display the classes they are attending. I think my model are correct since I am able to added classes for individual student but it could be my get end point which I set to includes all student with class.

My prisma model:

```
model Student {
  id             Int     @default(autoincrement()) @id
  firstName      String  
  lastName       String
  classes        CourseEnrollment[]
}

model Class {
  id             Int     @default(autoincrement()) @id
  name           String
  courseDetails  String?    
  members        CourseEnrollment[] 
}

model CourseEnrollment {
  studentId      Int
 student        Student  @relation(fields: [studentId], references: [id])
  classId        Int
  class          Class   @relation(fields: [classId], references: [id])
  @@id([studentId, classId])
}
```

Get endpoint:
// Maybe use select instead of include?

```
export default async function handler(req, res){
try{
 const result = await prisma.student.findMany({
    include: {
  classes: true,
     },
        });
       res.status(200).json(result);
    } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
    } 
}
```

My endpoint show:

```
{"id":13,"firstName":"John","lastName":"doe","classes":[{"studentId":13,"classId":9}]},
```

Student page where I map through all students:

```
    {data.map((student, id) => (
    <StudentCard key={id} student={student}/>
  ))}
```

Student Card taking in student prop:

```
const ClassCard = ({student}) => {
  return (
     <div className={styles.card}>
<div className={styles.card_wrapper}>
  <div className={styles.card_title}>
     <h3>{student.firstName}</h3>
     <h3>{student.lastName}</h3>
   </div>
   <div className={styles.student_card}>
     <h2>Class attending</h2>

 //I tried student.class.classId
     <h3>{student.class}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try [Include deeply nested relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#include-deeply-nested-relations)? `include: { classes: { include: { class: true }, }, },`

Comment: Thank you @mocherfaoui I included your code and it work. Is there difference between using select and include? Wat I am seeing when use include is that it also provide relation id as well as the name

Comment: you can see the answer below, or read the link I attached to learn more about the difference between `select` and `include`

Answer (score 1):

`select` allows us to select specific fields from a record. It allows us to return a limited subset of the fields instead of all the fields. Nested `select` allows us to include specific relation fields from a related record. `include` on the other hand allows us to return all relation fields. See the Prisma [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/select-fields) for in-depth examples of how select differs from include.